# momentjs wrong date returned

Tags: node.js, momentjs

Im using momentjs in nodejs app and trying to parse timestamp string with momentjs to compare two dates. My code is:

```
moment('11/04/2016 01:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
```

and the output is:

```
{ _date: Fri Nov 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) }
```

But with the given format im expecting the return date to be `Sun Apr 10 2016`.

Seems like the format option is not working or im missing something

Comment: Note that any field starting with _ is an internal variable. Don't use it. Use .format() instead.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me (`moment` version: 2.12.0)

```
var moment = require('moment')
var m = moment('11/04/2016 01:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
console.log(m.format('LLL')) // April 11, 2016 1:00 AM
```

Also changing days with months in both arguments works:

```
var m = moment('04/11/2016 01:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss') // same date as above
```

What version of `moment` are you using and how did you import it? How did you generate the output date? Is it just console.log?

(this should be a comment, but I wanted to add the code snippet)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample code to return a string in your output format

```
var moment = require('moment');

var now = moment();
var date = moment('11/04/2016 01:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');

console.log(now.format('ddd MMM D YYYY'));
console.log(date.format('ddd MMM D YYYY'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it was my mistake. I've installed `momentjs` which is not the official moment package. After installing the `moment` package instead `momentjs` all is working as expected.